# Setting authorization header of Httpclient return internal server error 500 repone why?

Tags: asp.net, api, authentication, jwt, authorization

I have a problem I don't know where , after setting `authorization header of HttpClient` return `internal server error 500`.

**Auth Controller Login Action**

```
namespace MagicVilla_Web.Controllers
{
    public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAuthService _authService;

        public AuthController(IAuthService authService) 
        {
            _authService = authService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            LoginRequestDTO loginRequestDTO = new LoginRequestDTO();
            return View(loginRequestDTO);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginRequestDTO loginRequestDTO)
        {
            APIResponse response = await _authService.LoginAsync<APIResponse>(loginRequestDTO);

            if (response != null && response.IsSuccess)
            {
                LoginResponseDTO model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponseDTO         (Convert.ToString(response.Result));
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.User.Name));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, model.User.Role));
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
                HttpContext.Session.SetString(SD.SessionToken, model.Token);

                return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", response.ErrorMessages.FirstOrDefault());
                return View(loginRequestDTO);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterationRequestDTO registerationRequestDTO)
        {
            APIResponse result = await _authService.RegisterAsync<APIResponse>(registerationRequestDTO);

            if (result != null && result.IsSuccess)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
            HttpContext.Session.SetString(SD.SessionToken, "");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AccessDenied()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Home Controller Index**

```
namespace MagicVilla_Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IVillaService villaService;
        private readonly IMapper mapper;

        public HomeController(IVillaService villaService, IMapper mapper)
        {
            this.villaService = villaService;
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            List<VillaDTO> list = new();
            var response = await villaService.GetAllAsync<APIResponse>(HttpContext.Session.GetString(SD.SessionToken));

            if (response != null && response.IsSuccess)
            {
                list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VillaDTO>>(Convert.ToString(response.Result));
            }

            return View(list);
        }
    }
}
```

**GetAllAsync From VillaService.cs**

```
public class VillaService : BaseService , IVillaService
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory clientFactory;
        private string villaUrl;

        public VillaService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, IConfiguration configuration) : base(clientFactory)
        {
            this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
            this.villaUrl = configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceUrls:VillaAPI");
        }

        public Task<T> GetAllAsync<T>(string token)
        {
            return SendAsync<T>(new APIRequest
            {
                ApiType = SD.ApiType.GET,
                Url = this.villaUrl + "/api/VillaAPI",
                Token = token
            });
        }
}
```

**Send Async From BaseService.cs**

Here response return internal server error 500 after pass the token in the header Authrization & not going to API endpoint .

```
namespace MagicVilla_Web.Services
{
    public class BaseService : IBaseServices
    {
        public APIResponse APIResponse { get; set; }
        public IHttpClientFactory httpClient { get; set; }

        public BaseService(IHttpClientFactory httpClient)
        {
            this.APIResponse = new();
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<T> SendAsync<T>(APIRequest apiRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = httpClient.CreateClient("MagicAPI");
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
                request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(apiRequest.Url);

                if (apiRequest.Data != null)
                {
                    request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apiRequest.Data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                }

                switch (apiRequest.ApiType)
                {
                    case SD.ApiType.POST:
                        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                        break;
                    case SD.ApiType.PUT:
                        request.Method = HttpMethod.Put;
                        break;
                    case SD.ApiType.DELETE:
                        request.Method = HttpMethod.Delete;
                        break;
                    default:
                        request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
                        break;
                }

                HttpResponseMessage response = null;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiRequest.Token))
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiRequest.Token);
                }

                response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                var apiContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                try
                {
                    APIResponse apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse>(apiContent);

                    if ((response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest || response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound))
                    {
                        apiResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                        apiResponse.IsSuccess = false;
                        var apiResponseSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apiResponse);
                        var apiResponseDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(apiResponseSerialized);

                        return apiResponseDeserialized;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    var exceptionResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(apiContent);
                    return exceptionResponse;
                }

                var APIResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(apiContent);

                return APIResponse;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var dto = new APIResponse
                {
                    ErrorMessages = new List<string> { Convert.ToString(e.Message) },
                    IsSuccess = false
                };

                var res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto);
                var apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(res);

                return apiResponse;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**VillaAPI Controller**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class VillaAPIController : ControllerBase
    {
        public readonly IVillaRepository villaRepository;
        public readonly IMapper mapper;
        protected APIResponse response;

        public VillaAPIController(IVillaRepository villaRepository, IMapper mapper)
        {
            this.villaRepository = villaRepository;
            this.mapper = mapper;
            this.response = new();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<APIResponse>>> GetVillas()
        {
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<Villa> villaList = await villaRepository.GetAllAsync();
                response.Result = mapper.Map<List<VillaDTO>>(villaList);
                response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.IsSuccess = false;
                response.ErrorMessages = new List<string> { ex.Message };
            }

            return Ok(response);
        }
}
```

Program.cs API

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(o => {
    o.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultSQLConnection"));
});

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingConfig));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IVillaRepository, VillaRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IVillaNumberRepository, VillaNumberRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

builder.Services.AddControllers(o => { 
    //o.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true; 
}).AddNewtonsoftJson().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

//get secret key from appSittings.json
var key = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiSettings:Secret");

//add Authentication Configurations
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    //configure the default authentication scheme and the default challenge scheme. Both of them we want to use JWT bearer defaults
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    //we have something called as add JWT bearer and then we can configure options on that.
    .AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; //we have the required https metadata
        x.SaveToken = true; //save the token
        x.Authority = "https://localhost:7003/";
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key)),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
        };
    });

//to enable bearer in swagger
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description =
            "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n " +
            "Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\n" +
            "Example: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            },
                Scheme = "oauth2",
                Name = "Bearer",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header
            },
            new List<string>()
        }
    });
});

//app => configured application
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Program.cs Web

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingConfig));

builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IVillaService, VillaService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IVillaService, VillaService>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IVillaNumberService, VillaNumberService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IVillaNumberService, VillaNumberService>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IAuthService, AuthService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Auth/AccessDenied";
       
    });

//add authorization
//builder.Services.AddAuthorization();


builder.Services.AddSession(options => 
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

If I turn off the authorization and not send the token in the header, everything works fine .[MagicVilla_VillaAPI](https://github.com/MoZytoon/MagicVilla) this project link in Github :https://github.com/MoZytoon/MagicVilla

Comment: What does your startup/program class look like?

Comment: Hello Tore . I have modified the question and added the Program.cs for API & Web .

Comment: You need to uncomment //builder.Services.AddAuthorization(); to get authorization to work in ASP.NET Core

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. The problem is that after logging in the API gives a response 500

Comment: What does the logs say?

Comment: I don't know but perhaps this is a conflict? registering he interface twice? builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IVillaService, VillaService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IVillaService, VillaService>();

Comment: No its not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the program.cs file for the Api. here :

```
x. Authority = "https://localhost:7003/";
```

When setting the the AddAuthentication .